# Solving the limit of an integral

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

Compute $$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{\left(4n-4-2a_n\right)}{\pi }\right)^n$$

Where $$a_n=\int _1^n\:\frac{2x^2}{x^2+1}dx$$

The integral I solved and I got $a_n=2(x-\arctan(x))$ Afterwards, after I took into account the fact that it's a definite integral, I got $a_n=2(n-\arctan(n)-\frac{\left(4-\pi\right)}{4})$

I tried to meddle with the limit a bit too and I got $\lim _{n\to \infty }3^n$, which would be $\infty$. Is this correct? Since it seemed way too easy. Could someone check my answer?

Comment: The limit should be $e^{-4/\pi}$

Comment: That doesn't look correct to me offhand, no. Why don't you write out 
$$
\left(\frac{\left(4n-4-2a_n\right)}{\pi }\right)^n
$$
for us by substituting in your value for $a_n$ and simplifying.

Comment: I don't thing the integral you got is correct.

Comment: $a_n$ is not a function of $x$, it should be a function of $n$. Don't even write $a_n=2(x-\arctan x)$.

Comment: So, $2a_n = 4n-4-4\arctan x+\pi$ so $4n-4-2a_n = 4\arctan n -\pi$.

Comment: Yes, the lower limit of the integral is 1. I solved the integral first as a non-definite one, hence the x. Afterwards it becomes a function of n after I substitute in the integral limits.

Comment: Yes @ThomasAndrews that's what I got also. So I only had to compute the $$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{\left(4arctan(n)-\pi\right)}{\pi }\right)^n$$ which I got as being $\lim _{n\to \infty }3^n$

Comment: @MikhaelM Why do you believe it is equivalent to taking the limit of $3^n$ for large $n$?

Comment: Definitely not $\lim 3^n$. @MikhaelM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{2x^2}{1+x^2}=2-\frac2{1+x^2}\implies$$

$$a_n=\left.\int_1^n\frac{2x^2}{1+x^2}dx=\left(2x-2\arctan x\right)\right|_1^n=2n-2\arctan n-2+\frac\pi2\implies$$

$$\frac{4n-4-2a_n}\pi=\frac{4\arctan n}\pi-1\implies$$

$$\left(\frac{4n-4-2a_n}\pi\right)^n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}...$$

For the last limit, you may want to use the exponential function:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\log\left(\frac{4\arctan n}\pi-1\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log\left(\frac{4\arctan n}\pi-1\right)}{\frac1n}\stackrel{l'H}=$$

$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac\pi{4\arctan n-\pi}\frac4{\pi(1+n^2)}}{-\frac1{n^2}}=-\frac4\pi$$

Comment: Why spend so much time repeating the first part that the OP has already done?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews (1) Because I didn't notice, (2) Because after I notice (now), I can't see clearly whether it is the same thing. (3) It is **not** "so much time"...at least not for me :)

Comment: But why is that limit at the end $\frac{-4}{\pi }$? :S

Comment: @MikhaelM  This is simply a limit...not even a hard one: $$\frac{-4}{4\arctan n-\pi}\cdot\frac{n^2}{1+n^2}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac{-4}{4\frac\pi2-\pi} \cdot1=-\frac4\pi$$

Comment: Thank you @Timbuc . I still got a lot of work to do with limits :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{4n - 4 - 2a_n}{\pi}\right) = \lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{4 \arctan n}{\pi} - 1\right)^n$$

Now, to compute the latter limit, consider $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \exp \log \left(\frac{4 \arctan n}{\pi} - 1\right)^n = \lim_{n\to \infty} \exp \left(n \log \left(\frac{4 \arctan n}{\pi} - 1\right) \right)$$

Now use L'Hopital on the inside of the $\exp$ function.

Comment: Yes, that's where I got as well. Isn't this equal to $$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{\left(4\pi\right)}{\pi }-1\right)^n$$ which would be $3^n$ ?

Comment: It's not $3^n$.

Comment: @MikhaelM, two things. 1)
 $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \arctan (n) = \pi /2$$

2) In general,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} (f(n))^n \not= (\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n))^n$$

Comment: @FH93 Thanks for the reply. This is where I got stuck. Going to see how to solve the limit now.